# Scipy Butterworth bandpass filter does not return correct amplitudes

Tags: python, filter, scipy, butterworth, bandpass-filter

I am trying to create a bandpass filter using SciPy Butterworth, but it is not returning correct amplitudes (although it seems to get the periods right). First, I create a wave that is a combination of three waves:

```python
x = np.arange(1,365,1)
y1 = 1*np.sin( (1/10) * x)
y2 = 5*np.sin( (1/45) * x)
y3 = 10*np.sin( (1/120) * x)

y_total = y1 + y2 + y3
```

Then I apply my filter:

```python
import math
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter

def firstNonNan(listfloats):
    for item in listfloats:
        if math.isnan(item) == False:
            #print(item)
            return item

def butter_bandpass(highcut, lowcut, fs, order=2):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    high = highcut / nyq

    low = lowcut / nyq

    b, a = butter(order, [high, low], btype='band')
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, cap, cap1, order=2):
    highcut = 1/cap

    lowcut = 1/cap1

    fs = 1
    b, a = butter_bandpass(highcut,lowcut, fs, order=order)

    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

def butter_hpf(data, cap, cap1):
    indc = firstNonNan(list(data))
    year1 = list(np.random.uniform(low=indc-0.1, high=indc+0.1, size=(cap,))) + list(data)
    return(butter_bandpass_filter(year1, cap, cap1)[cap:])
```

(where I use randomly generated data on either end to try and deal with edge effects)

The filter is applied like this:

```python
plt.scatter(x,y_total)

plt.scatter(x,butter_hpf(y_total,96,30))
```

where the `butter_hpf` function takes the time series and the high and low cutoff periods. I would expect it to return only a single sine wave with an amplitude of 5, but as you can see below, the amplitude is too small and the wave is not exactly just a sine wave (blue is input wave, orange is the filter output). How can I fix my filter?

[image: time series plot]

Comment: Might be interesting to see the recommended `order` from [`butterord`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.buttord.html).

Answer (score 0):

`np.sin` and most (probably all) other Scipy base trigonometric functions work in radians; you're working in "cycles"; your frequencies are (I think) "per day", but you need to scale them to "radians per day" for generating `y1`, etc.

The result still isn't great, though it may be good enough.  Using `filtfilt` gives a small improvement.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter, filtfilt, iirdesign, sosfilt

def firstNonNan(listfloats):
    for item in listfloats:
        if math.isnan(item) == False:
            #print(item)
            return item

def butter_bandpass(highcut, lowcut, fs, order=2):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    high = highcut / nyq

    low = lowcut / nyq

    b, a = butter(order, [high, low], btype='band')
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, cap, cap1, order=2):
    highcut = 1/cap

    lowcut = 1/cap1

    fs = 1
    b, a = butter_bandpass(highcut,lowcut, fs, order=order)

    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

def butter_hpf(data, cap, cap1):
    indc = firstNonNan(list(data))
    year1 = list(np.random.uniform(low=indc-0.1, high=indc+0.1, size=(cap,))) + list(data)
    return(butter_bandpass_filter(year1, cap, cap1)[cap:])


x = np.arange(1,365,1)
y1 = 1*np.sin( 2*np.pi*(1/10) * x)
y2 = 5*np.sin( 2*np.pi*(1/45) * x)
y3 = 10*np.sin( 2*np.pi*(1/120) * x)

y_total = y1 + y2 + y3

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y_total)
ax.plot(x,butter_hpf(y_total,96,30))
ax.plot(x,y2)
ax.legend(['noisy','filtered','desired'])
ax.set_title('using rad/day')

# filtfilt
b, a = butter(2, [1/96, 1/30], btype='band', fs=1)
yff = filtfilt(b, a, y_total, method='gust')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y_total)
ax.plot(x,yff)
ax.plot(x,y2)
ax.legend(['noisy','filtered','desired'])
ax.set_title('using rad/day and filtfilt')
```

[image: Result showing rad/day change]

[image: Result showing rad/day change and filtfilt]